# What's the purpose of this part of code in this JS addEvent function implementation of "Pro JavaScript Techniques"?

Tags: javascript, event-listener

In the "Pro JavaScript Techniques" book, there's an `addEvent` function with the following code:

```
function addEvent(element, type, handler) {
    // assign each event handler a unique ID
    if (!handler.$$guid) handler.$$guid = addEvent.guid++;

    // create a hash table of event types for the element
    if (!element.events) element.events = {};

    // create a hash table of event handlers for each element/event pair
    var handlers = element.events[type];
    if (!handlers) {
        handlers = element.events[type] = {};

        // What's the purpose of this if???
        // store the existing event handler (if there is one)
        if (element["on" + type]) {
            handlers[0] = element["on" + type];
        }
    }

    // store the event handler in the hash table
    handlers[handler.$$guid] = handler;

    // assign a global event handler to do all the work
    element["on" + type] = handleEvent;
}
```

Now I understand most part of it and understand that that the creation of that `hash table of event handlers for each element/event pair` is made only one for each element/event the first time only when an event handler is added to an element which didn't have a previous event handler for that event. But I didn't understand the `store existing event handler (if there is one)` part. In the book doesn't say anything about it and the comment `store the existing event handler (if there is one)` (what event handler?) didn't make it clear to me. What's its purpose?

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: if a on???? handler has been assigned, then store it ... eg element.onclick, element.onchange, element.onblur etc

Comment: But I didn't assign a handler through on????, hence I write such an `addEvent` function, because I do not want to use `onclick` but `addEvent(element, "click", fn);`. Does it refer to e.g. external libraries codes which might add events through the `on????` property?

Comment: @tonix—you may not be the only one adding listeners to elements in the page. If you are, you certainly don't need all that cruft (and if you stick to standard DOM events and use *addEventListener*, you likely don't need it ever).

Comment: `But I didn't assign a handler through on????` great, but if you did, it would save it. This code is generic, not written with your exact requirements in mind. If you want to change it, then change it, there's no harm in leaving it the way it is, there's potential harm in changing it ... your choice, albert

Comment: don't worry about it really. that's for adding many inline events on one element, but you shouldn't do that. use addEventListener() instead of inline events. the book is either really outdated or poorly written.

Comment: Thanks, know it became clearer!

Answer (score 0):

To, um... to store the existing handler.

When you add an event, if there is already a handler for that event and you're binding a second event of the same type to the same element, then it saves the existing handler and basically appends the new handler to it. Otherwise you would overwrite the old event, which this "addEvent" function is designed to prevent.

Comment: Well, it is intended to save a handler that e.g. a library may have added through the "onxxxx" property of the element?